# "Unknown Type" runtime error when calling std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, types, segmentation-fault

I am using a library ([C++ REST SDK](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaces.html)) in which I can set a handler for a specific event. Precisely I set a close handler which gets called when a websocket connection gets closed by the client(me) or the server. The handler is set like this:

```
// WebsocketClient is my own custom class
// m_pclClient holds the connection (of type websocket_callback_client)
std::function<void(web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status close_status, const utility::string_t &reason, const std::error_code &error)> handler(std::bind(&WebsocketClient::close_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));

this->m_pclClient->set_close_handler(handler);
```

When I now close the connection the library handles the closing procedure and, after finishing the process, calls `handler` with its three parameters.

When closing the connection an error occurs. I am not sure if it's a bug inside the library or my mistake. `gdb` output when closing the connection:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffe1c23700 (LWP 13849)]
0x00000000004e20b7 in std::__invoke_impl<void, void (WebsocketClient::* const&)(web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status, std::string const&, std::error_code const&), WebsocketClient*&, web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status, std::string const&, std::error_code const&>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (WebsocketClient::* const&)(web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status, std::string const&, std::error_code const&), WebsocketClient*&, web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status&&, std::string const&, std::error_code const&) (__f=
    @0x80d290: (void (WebsocketClient::*)(WebsocketClient * const, web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status, const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > &, const std::error_code &)) 0x4cf120 <WebsocketClient::close_handler(web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status, std::string const&, std::error_code const&)>, __t=@0x80d2a0: 0x8081f8, 
    __args#0=<unknown type in /path/to/executable, CU 0x1d28f4, DIE 0x21f672>, __args#1="TLS Short Read", __args#2=...) at /usr/include/c++/6/functional:235
235       return ((*std::forward<_Tp>(__t)).*__f)(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

There's obviously a problem with argument #0: `web::websockets::client::websocket_close_status close_status`.

It seems that when the handler should be invoked, the type of the first argument is unknown. See in the gdb output: "__args#0= < unknown type in /path/to/executable"

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: It may just be gdb not having proper debug symbols. You have better chances of a proper answer if you provide a [mcve].

Comment: @nwp I am sure that it is not gdb, because before using std::function I used a lambda function which took the first argument as const lvalue reference. With this version, the error occured when I wanted to assign the value of the first argument to a local variable, so there seems to be something wrong with the first argument. Providing a short example is hard because it is very complex code, but I will try to.

Comment: Your runtime error is a segmentation fault.  The unknown type error is because the debugger/crash dump support doesn't have type info for that first parameter.